# multiple devise models with multiple login pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I created three devise models user, admin, trainer. For user and admin i want login with email and password. For trainer I want login with username and password. How we can achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Your Users and Admin should already be logging in with email and password by default with Devise.

To set up login with username for your Trainers checkout this link.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address

This will allow your Trainers to login with either username or email.  You can display either on the pages because we are adding a username migration to the trainers model.

You will also need to add field to the Trainer signup page.